# Error : python-config cannot be found in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, dbus, python-config

The following error prevents me from installing `dbus-python` via `pip3`:

```
configure: error: cannot find python3.6-config or python-config in PATH
```

`python-config` was installed via `pip3` without an issue, and I thought this would put it in PATH (but it didn't?) The complete output can be seen at the end of this post.

The same happens when using Python 2.7. Both commands below yield the same error:

```
pip install --user dbus-python
pip3 install --user dbus-python
```

Ultimately my goal is to install `AutoKey` (autokey-py3), however, its `setup.py` requires `dbus-python` and thus the same error occurs. I'm not sure what to do next as `dbus-python` is properly installed via `dnf` (I'm on Fedora27). If it's of any help, the packages dbus-devel and dbus-glib-devel are also installed successfully via dnf.

Moreover, importing dbus in Python works fine (because it's installed via dnf, I suppose), but for some reason the installation via pip3 fails.

Thanks!

PS: below is the complete output that shows the error.

```
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uajq6lpe-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
running install
running build
creating /tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/build
creating /tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for native Windows host... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for inline... inline
checking whether /usr/bin/python3 version is >= 2.6... yes
checking for /usr/bin/python3 version... 3.6
checking for /usr/bin/python3 platform... linux
checking for /usr/bin/python3 script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python3.6/site-packages
checking for /usr/bin/python3 extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
checking for python3.6-config... no
checking for python-config... no
configure: error: cannot find python3.6-config or python-config in PATH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/setup.py", line 106, in <module>
    'build_ext': BuildExt,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 555, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/setup.py", line 62, in run
    cwd=builddir)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/configure', '--disable-maintainer-mode', 'PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3', '--prefix=/tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/prefix']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

----------------------------------------
```

> Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-uajq6lpe-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-x10w__hm/dbus-python/